# How do I put a condition of items in a for loop to append only items that have a % at the end of the string?

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am looking to run a "for loop" on the result of a select query but only include the items that have a percent sign at the end of the string. The select string outputs stuff with html code in it so I am cleaning it with the .text function. I'm doing something wrong with regex (can't seem to properly write that code yet), but I'm sure the answer lies somewhere there. Can anyone help me add an if clause that will allow me to filter out anything that doesnt have a % at the end of the text?

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

```
mylist = []
towns = selsoup.select('span.umbrage')
for town in towns:
    town = town.text
{need if filter step here}
    mylist.append(town)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`str.endswith`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith):

```
for town in towns:
    town = town.text
    if town.endswith('%'):
        mylist.append(town)
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the answer by @ForceBru as it is easy to follow. However, I am also a huge fan of list comprehensions and this problem seem a perfect match for one:

```
towns = selsoup.select('span.umbrage')
mylist = [town.text for town in towns if town.text.endswith('%')]
```